# Pagination ajax not working, return a error 400 bad request

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to do ajax pagination in wordpress, but I get a 400 bad request error without further information when I try to use it.

all the php code is in the functions.php file.

This is my code:

**PHP**

loading my javascript:

```php
function enqueue_pagination_script()
{
    $pages = [
        'inversion-y-gestion-presupuestaria',
        'acuerdos-de-entrada-gestionada',
    ];
    if (is_page($pages)) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'pagination-script',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-querys.js',
            ['jquery'],
            '1.0.0',
            true
        );
        $variable_to_js = [
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        ];
        wp_localize_script('pagination-script', 'ajax_object', $variable_to_js);
    }
}
```

The first function is to make pagination by buttons, which is the one that brings the pagination links:

```php-template
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_ajax_multimedia', 'filter_ajax_multimedia');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_ajax_multimedia', 'filter_ajax_multimedia');

function filter_ajax_multimedia()
{
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : '';

    $categoria = isset($_POST['categoria'])
        ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['categoria'])
        : '';

    if ($categoria === 'todos') {
        $query_args = [
            'post_type' => 'recursos_multimedia',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'posts_per_page' => '12',
            'offset' => '0',
            'paged' => '1',
            // 'page'           => '2',
        ];
        // var_dump('todos');
        // $wp_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
    } else {
        $query_args = [
            'post_type' => 'recursos_multimedia',
            // 'posts_per_page' => $countPPP,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'posts_per_page' => '12',
            'offset' => '0',
            'paged' => '1',
            // 'orderby' => 'date',
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $categoria,
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
    if ($wp_query->have_posts()):
        ob_start();
        $categorias = [];
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()):

            $wp_query->the_post();
            $term = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'categoria');
            foreach ($term as $term) {
                $categorias[] = $term->slug;
            }
            ?>
      <div class="show-on-scroll item <?php echo $term->slug; ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <span class="videoMask">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium'); ?>" alt="">
          </span>
          <div class="categoriaRecursoMultimedia <?php echo $term->slug; ?>">
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
          </div>
          <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(the_title(), 10, '...'); ?></p>
        </a>
      </div>
    <?php
        endwhile;
        $current_category = isset($term->slug) ? $term->slug : '';
        // Obtén los enlaces de paginación
        $pagination = paginate_links([
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'current' => max(1, $paged),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all' => false,
            'type' => 'array',
            'prev_next' => true,
            // 'end_size'       => 4,
            'prev_text' => __(
                '<img src="' .
                    get_template_directory_uri() .
                    '/images/icons8-atras.svg" />'
            ),
            'next_text' => __(
                '<img src="' .
                    get_template_directory_uri() .
                    '/images/icons8-adelante.svg" />'
            ),
        ]);

        $response = [
            'type' => 'success',
            'html' => ob_get_clean(),
            'page' => $paged,
            'pagination' => $pagination, // Agrega los enlaces de paginación a la respuesta
            'current_category' => $current_category,
        ];
        // $response   = array(
        //   'type'  => 'success',
        //   'html'  => ob_get_clean(),
        //   'page'  => $paged
        // );
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else:
        __('No News');
        $response = [
            'type' => 'failure',
            'html' => 'No News',
        ];
    endif;
    wp_send_json_success($response);
    wp_die();
}
```

This second function is the one that fulfills pagination by page numbers.

```php-template
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pagination_ajax_custom', 'pagination_ajax_custom');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_pagination_ajax_custom', 'pagination_ajax_custom');

function pagination_ajax_custom()
{
    $paged_pagination = isset($_POST['page'])
        ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['page'])
        : '';
    $categoria_pagination = isset($_POST['categoria'])
        ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['categoria'])
        : '';
    $post_type_pagination = isset($_POST['post_type'])
        ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['post_type'])
        : '';
    $taxonomy_pagination = isset($_POST['taxonomy'])
        ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['taxonomy'])
        : '';

    $query_args_pagination = [
        'post_type' => $post_type_pagination,
        // 'posts_per_page' => $countPPP,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => '12',
        'offset' => '0',
        'paged' => $paged_pagination,
        // 'orderby' => 'date',
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_pagination,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $categoria_pagination,
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $wp_query_pagination = new WP_Query($query_args_pagination);
    if ($wp_query_pagination->have_posts()):
        ob_start();
        $categorias_pagination = [];
        while ($wp_query_pagination->have_posts()):

            $wp_query_pagination->the_post();
            $term_pagination = get_the_terms(
                get_the_ID(),
                $taxonomy_pagination
            );
            foreach ($term_pagination as $term_pagination) {
                $categorias_pagination[] = $term_pagination->slug;
            }
            ?>
      <div class="show-on-scroll item <?php echo $term_pagination->slug; ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <span class="videoMask">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium'); ?>" alt="">
          </span>
          <div class="categoriaRecursoMultimedia <?php echo $term_pagination->slug; ?>">
            <?php echo $term_pagination->name; ?>
          </div>
          <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(the_title(), 10, '...'); ?></p>
        </a>
      </div>
    <?php
        endwhile;
        $current_category_pagination = isset($term_pagination->slug)
            ? $term_pagination->slug
            : '';
        $pagination_pagination = paginate_links([
            'total' => $wp_query_pagination->max_num_pages,
            'current' => max(1, $paged_pagination),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all' => false,
            'type' => 'array',
            'prev_next' => true,
            // 'end_size'       => 4,
            'prev_text' => __(
                '<img src="' .
                    get_template_directory_uri() .
                    '/images/icons8-atras.svg" />'
            ),
            'next_text' => __(
                '<img src="' .
                    get_template_directory_uri() .
                    '/images/icons8-adelante.svg" />'
            ),
        ]);
        $response_pagination = [
            'type' => 'success',
            'html' => ob_get_clean(),
            'page' => $paged_pagination,
            'pagination' => $pagination_pagination, // Agrega los enlaces de paginación a la respuesta
            'current_category' => $current_category_pagination,
        ];
        // $response   = array(
        //   'type'  => 'success',
        //   'html'  => ob_get_clean(),
        //   'page'  => $paged
        // );
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else:
        __('No News');
        $response_pagination = [
            'type' => 'failure',
            'html' => 'No News',
        ];
    endif;
    wp_send_json_success($response_pagination);
    wp_die();
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".filtroRecursoMultimedia").click(function () {
    // Traer todos los atributos que nos serviran para consultas con nuestras peticiones ajax
    const categorie = $(this).attr("data-categorie");
    const taxonomy = $(this).attr("data-taxonomy");
    const post_type = $(this).attr("data-post");
    const ajaxURL = ajax_object.ajax_url; // Esta variable se obtiene automaticamente por wordpress, revisar la carga de este script en el archivo functions.php
    $.ajax({
      url: ajaxURL,
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        // page: 1,
        action: "filter_ajax_multimedia", //nombre de la funcion de php
        categoria: categorie,
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // console.log('Error en la solicitud Ajax:', errorThrown);
      },
      success: function (response) {
        switch (response.data.type) {
          case "success":
            // $('.sunset-load-more').attr('data-page', response.data.page);
            /* you need remove last five then use html method and if you want append then use append method */
            $(".gridMultimedia").html(response.data.html);
            if (response.data.pagination) {
              const currentCategory = response.data.current_category;
              const paginationHtml = response.data.pagination
                .map((link) => {
                  const page = $(link).text();
                  return $(link)
                    .attr("data-page", page)
                    .attr("data-current-category", currentCategory)
                    .attr("data-post-type", post_type)
                    .attr("data-taxonomy", taxonomy)[0].outerHTML;
                })
                .join("");

              $("#pagination-links-recursos").on(
                "click",
                ".page-numbers",
                function (event) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  const clickedPage = $(this).attr("data-page");
                  const clickedCategory = $(this).attr("data-current-category");
                  const clickedPostType = $(this).attr("data-post-type");
                  const clickedTaxonomy = $(this).attr("data-taxonomy");
                  ajax_pagination_query(
                    clickedPostType,
                    clickedTaxonomy,
                    clickedCategory,
                    clickedPage,
                  );
                },
              );
              $("#pagination-links-recursos").html(paginationHtml);
            } else {
              $("#pagination-links-recursos").html("");
            }
            break;
          case "failure":
            $(".gridMultimedia").html(response.data.html);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      },
    });
  });
  // Función para páginacion

  function ajax_pagination_query(post_type, taxonomy, categoria, page) {
    $.ajax({
      url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        action: "pagination_ajax_custom", //nombre de la funcion de php
        post_type: post_type,
        page: page,
        taxonomy: taxonomy,
        categoria: categoria,
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
      success: function (response) {
        switch (response.data.type) {
          case "success":
            // $('.sunset-load-more').attr('data-page', response.data.page);
            /* you need remove last five then use html method and if you want append then use append method */
            $(".gridMultimedia").html(response.data.html);
            if (response.data.pagination) {
              const currentCategory = response.data.current_category;
              const paginationHtml = response.data.pagination
                .map((link) => {
                  const page = $(link).text();
                  return $(link)
                    .attr("data-page", page)
                    .attr("data-current-category", currentCategory)
                    .attr("data-post-type", post_type)
                    .attr("data-taxonomy", taxonomy)[0].outerHTML;
                })
                .join("");

              $("#pagination-links-recursos").on(
                "click",
                ".page-numbers",
                function (event) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                },
              );
              $("#pagination-links-recursos").html(paginationHtml);
            } else {
              $("#pagination-links-recursos").html("");
            }
            break;
          case "failure":
            $(".gridMultimedia").html(response.data.html);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      },
    });
  }
});
```

These are the buttons where I get the attributes that I use in the javascript:

```php-template
<button data-taxonomy="categoria" data-post="recursos_multimedia" data-categorie="todos" class="filtroRecursoMultimedia todos active">Todos los recursos multimedia</button>
<?php
$args = [
    'type' => 'recursos_multimedia',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'parent' => '',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
    'pad_counts' => false,
];

$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $url = get_term_link($category); ?>
<button data-taxonomy="categoria" data-post="recursos_multimedia" data-categorie="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" class="filtroRecursoMultimedia <?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></button>
<?php
}


?>
```

I checked in the console and I only got a 400 bad request error and in the response there is no more information than a "0", the payload is exactly what I need, I don't know what could be failing, I am checking very well and I can't find any logic to the error , I appreciate you helping me.

Comment: `add_action('wp_ajax_filter_pagination_ajax_custom'` - wrong naming there; your `action` parameter value that you are sending is `pagination_ajax_custom`, so the `filter_` part does not belong in there.

Comment: @CBroe I spent quite some time looking for the error, thank you.